# Build storefront with theme missing source files

Tags: shopware6

I have Shopware installed with some theme free theme from the official store. I wanted to extend this theme, so I've created my custom theme and I wanted to build it using bin/build-storefront.sh script, but the custom theme that I have downloaded doesn't contain all source files, only compiled js. There is still the main.js file but it's trying to register plugins that are missing.
Is there any way to skip building this plugin and use already build files for it?

For now, I cannot build and even start a watcher :(

Error during build

```
ERROR in /var/www/html/vendor/store.shopware.com/[theme-name]/src/Resources/app/storefront/src/main.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './core/[plugin1].plugin' in '/var/www/html/vendor/store.shopware.com/[theme-name]/src/Resources/app/storefront/src'

ERROR in /var/www/html/vendor/store.shopware.com/[theme-name]/src/Resources/app/storefront/src/main.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './core/[plugin2].plugin' in '/var/www/html/vendor/store.shopware.com/[theme-name]/src/Resources/app/storefront/src'
```

I would expect to be able to build my theme without switching the other theme off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest contacting the theme manufacturer and asking them to include the sources. I don't know exactly, but I'm fairly positive that this is not in line with the guidelines of the extension store as well. Using the already compiled files in the build process might work but is at least very prone to fail because the sources are heavily compressed during the compilation.